# Create new SQLDataAdapter for each iterate

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having problem with create SqlDataAdapter for each iterate in for loop.
Here is what im trying to do :

I have tabControl and I'm create dataGridView on each of them, for every dataGridView I'm creating dataTable and I want to fill dataTable when the SqlDataAdapter.Name.Contains(dataTable.TableName).

I'm not sure if it's correct way to do this.

I'm creating DataGridView this way :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            tabControl_Roz.TabPages.Add("Print " + lista[i]);
            var dataGridView = new DataGridView()
            {
                Name = "dataGridView_" + lista[i],
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
         }
```

DataTable :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable()
            {
                TableName = "" + lista[i]
            };
            dtList.Add(dataTable);
        }
```

And it works correct but the problem with SqlDataAdapter is that I can't to do it this same way and then manipulate the SQL Query depends of SqlDataAdapterName, it should be like this :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter()
            {
                Name = "sda" + lista[i]
            };
            sda.List.Add(dataAdapter);
        }
```

But it doesn't work cause method "Name" don't exist.
Can some one help me doing this ? Or show me any other way how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` has no `Name`. But it's not clear why you need to use multiple `DataAdapter`'s anyway. Maybe you should use a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>` or a `DataSet` or something like that.

Comment: This maybe is an odd way of doing this so you seem to have a list of I guess tables, you then make a gridview for each, a datatable for each, and an adapter.. why not just make a class/struct for each and have a list of those classes/structs

Comment: This is why I'v said when some1 know better way then he can tell me how :) Im creating many DataTables/DataGridView/SqlDataAdapters cause I want to run different SQL Query in each SqlDataAdapter and Fill dataTable when dt.TableName = sda.Name and then fill DataGridView when dgv.Name = dt.Table

Comment: Tim Schmelter, can I contact you any way ? I have some questions, also on e-mail I could send you code sample.